# How to test for dropped JAVA database connections

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/) connection pool -

```
Class jdbcClass = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Driver jdbcDriver = (Driver)jdbcClass.newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(jdbcDriver);
pool = new ConnectionPool("pool",5,10,30,180,"jdbc:sqlserver://serverip", "login", "password");
```

and I get connections by

```
pool.getConnection(500);
```

The problem I have is that the application hangs if the network connection is lost to the server. The 500mS timeout provided to the  doesn't actually timeout and my application just hangs if there is no network connection.

What is the best way to check if the connection is lost or if the connection times out? I want it to fail and return null if there is no connection after 500mS

Comment: do you mean getConnection(500) is succeeding, but subsequently the connection is lost, or getConnection(500) never returns?

Comment: try showing the rest of the code

Comment: If you are getting a connection object and then during in between your transaction the connection got lost. Then may be you can try using conn.isValid() each time you do a transaction.

Comment: getConnection(500) never returns if the link is lost.